# Use case with the ability of user manager (like organization)

Tags: use-case, user-management

I want to have a use case model with the ability of user manager!

I have problem in drawing use-case under these conditions
groups can be defined
And people in "manager" group can assign their employees to other groups (even a manager can add one of  his employees' to manager group)

Answer (score 1):

Well,

Drawing the use case is the easyist thing. I think you get lost in details.

First Question:

> Who will use your system?[ directly]

Second Question:

> What can they able to do with your system? [ main golas, not details]

And we get simple diagram....

[image]

You can check my answer for similiar question: [Help deciding on Use Case Diagram parts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829062/help-deciding-on-use-case-diagram-parts)